# How to pass multiple parameters by jQuery.ajax() to PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a simple load more style script that works fine on the index page, where only one parameter is sent via ajax

```
    $(function() {//When the Dom is ready
    $('.load_more').live("click",function() {//If user clicks on hyperlink with class  name = load_more
        var last_msg_id = $(this).attr("id");//Get the id of this hyperlink this id indicate the row id in the database
        if(last_msg_id!='end'){//if  the hyperlink id is not equal to "end"
            $.ajax({//Make the Ajax Request
                type: "POST",
                url: "index_more.php",
                data: "lastmsg="+ last_msg_id,
                beforeSend:  function() {
                    $('a.load_more').html('<img src="loading.gif" />');//Loading image during the Ajax Request
                },
                success: function(html){//html = the server response html code
                    $("#more").remove();//Remove the div with id=more
                    $("ul#updates").append(html);//Append the html returned by the server .
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

With this HTML/PHP

```
<div id="more">
 <a  id="<?php echo $msg_id; ?>" class="load_more" href="#">more</a>
</div>
```

However, I want to add another php variable so that it can also work with particular categories, I have no problems writing the HTML and PHP but I am new to Jquery and struggling to edit the script to include the additional parameter if it is set.  This is the HTML that I am thinking of using, just struggling with editing the JQuery

```
<div id="more"class="<?php echo $cat_id;?>">
<a id="<?php echo $msg_id;?>" class="load_more2" href="#">more</a>
</div>
```

As always any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What additional parameter are you trying to add?

Comment: @user866190 Is using an additional class tag in your HTML the only way to pass a second variable? What would you do if you needed to pass three, or more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass multiple URL params in the `data` portion of your ajax call.

```
data: "lastmsg="+ last_msg_id +"&otherparam="+ other_param
```

On the PHP side, you'd just process these as you already are.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am wondering if I have to create a variable for the additional parameter that is set just like the first one..?

Comment: In my answer, you'd have to create other_param and set its value. You can also just pass it in the string like this: `data: "lastmsg="+ last_msg_id +"&otherparam=tacos"`.

Answer (score 6):

You can set

```
data = {onevar:'oneval', twovar:'twoval'}
```

And both key/value pairs will be sent.

See [Jquery ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

If you look under the `data` section, you can see that you can pass a query string like you are, an array, or an object.  If you were to use the same method you already are using then your `data` value would be like `"lastmsg="+ last_msg_id + "&otherthing=" + otherthing`,

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code:

```
$.ajax({//Make the Ajax Request
                type: "POST",
                url: "index_more.php",
                data: {var1: "value1", var2: "value2"},
                beforeSend:  function() {
                    $('a.load_more').html('<img src="loading.gif" />');//Loading image during the Ajax Request
                },
                success: function(html){//html = the server response html code
                    $("#more").remove();//Remove the div with id=more
                    $("ul#updates").append(html);//Append the html returned by the server .
                }
            });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try It:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ lastmsg: last_msg_id, secondparam: second_param_value});
```

You can add more parameters separating them  by comma (,).